# How to wrap each divs to multiple elements

Tags: javascript

This is how it is:

```
<button> One <button> 
<button> Two <button> 
<button> Three <button>
```

what I'm trying to do is like this:

```
<div><button> One <button></div> 
<div><button> Two <button></div>   
<div><button> Three <button></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var theDivs = document.createElement("div");

var divWrapper = new Array(3).fill(theDivs);

for (var i = 0; i < divWrapper.length; i++) {

  divWrapper[0].appendChild(buttonOne);
  divWrapper[1].appendChild(buttonTwo);
  divWrapper[2].appendChild(buttonThree);

  document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[0]);
  document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[1]);
  document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[2]);

};
```

Comment: Your problem is that you're using the same `<div>` element. You need to create separate ones

Comment: doing this in js.

Comment: creating new divs here `var divWrapper = new Array(3).fill(theDivs);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create separate `<div>` elements, one on each loop iteration, or else all of the array elements will be the same `<div>`.

Here's what you're doing:

```
var divWrapper = new Array(3).fill(theDivs);
```

This means all three elements of the `divWrapper` array are the reference to the same `<div>` object, which you don't want.

Also, you can create DRY-er code by only creating and appending elements once, inside the loop, instead of copying it three times like you do here:

```
divWrapper[0].appendChild(buttonOne);
divWrapper[1].appendChild(buttonTwo);
divWrapper[2].appendChild(buttonThree);

document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[0]);
document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[1]);
document.body.appendChild(divWrapper[2]);
```

Demo:

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var divWrapper = document.createElement("div");
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = i + 1;

  divWrapper.appendChild(button);
  document.body.appendChild(divWrapper);
};
```

```css
div {   /* make <div>s clearer */
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

---

As per your comment, below is a demo to show you what will happen if you do it your way, filling an array with one element. Although you are accessing different elements of the array with `divWrappers[i]` in the loop, they all refer to the same object, so that all the buttons are added to the same `<div>`.

```js
var divWrapper = document.createElement("div");
var divWrappers = Array(3).fill(divWrapper);

for (var i = 0; i < divWrappers.length; i++) {
  var button = document.createElement("button");
  button.textContent = i + 1;

  divWrappers[i].appendChild(button);
  document.body.appendChild(divWrappers[i]);
};
```

```css
div {
  background-color: grey;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: I thought i was creating and inserting them in the array `var divWrapper = new Array(3).fill(theDivs);` because in console it shows 3 divs in array.

Comment: @Deke I edited my answer to show you what will happen if you create the array that way.

Answer (score -1):

Try using jQuery's [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

Include jQuery in your HTML (see the website above if you need further information on how to do that).

Then use:

```
$(":button").wrapAll("<div class=''/>");
```

Comment: There's a large overhead for adding a library like jQuery just for a single, simple functionality.